# Maven: how to identify jar files by SHA

Tags: java, ant, maven, jar

I've inherited an Ant-based project that has over 80MB of jar files in a lib dir. I'd like to convert it to Maven. The jar files are named very simply, like `quartz.jar`. Since there is no indication of group id, much less version, converting this to `pom.xml` format is going to be very painful.

**Is there a service or API that will return the Maven coordinates (group, artifact, version) for a jar file, given its SHA?**

My fallback will be to examine the `MANIFEST` file from each jar, which will at least give me version info, if not specific Maven coordinates.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ah, looks like I needed to Google on "checksum search", rather than "SHA". That turned up this page:

[How to Convert from Ant to Maven in 5 Minutes](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/04/how-to-convert-from-ant-to-maven-in-5-minutes/)

... which explains that you can use the `checksum search` on [this page](https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html).

Based on this info, I just coded up a [quick project](https://github.com/armhold/Provenance) on Github that will use this API and generate the XML dependencies stanza automatically. You can use it like:

```
$ java com.armhold.Provenance lib_dir
```

And it will print out the Maven coords for each jar file it finds.